# Search for rails that does ranking of results according to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to add search functionality to my Rails website. The search has to rank results according to relevancy. By this I mean if the search occurs in the post title it should be given higher score than post body and post comments. Also, it would be nice to rank a post higher if the phrase occurred more than once. I know that Sphinx(with thinking_sphinx plugin) does that as I have used before but it's an overkill for this project.

I looked into using SearchLogic but it doesn't seem to have that out of the box.

Do you know if I can tweak SearchLogic to do that or if there is another simple plugin that might do?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use acts_as_ferret =)

for using acts_as_ferret:
http://github.com/jkraemer/acts_as_ferret

for boosting results:
http://rm.jkraemer.net/wiki/aaf/AdvancedUsage

Answer (score 0):

If thinking sphinx does it then go with it! I'd rather an overkill solution that does the job than an undercooked solution anyday!